# How to read Response Status code in HTTP Delete with body in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am unable to send delete with body from Angular to backend Api and reading response status code as well?

I have tried :

```
const options : {
         headers : //passing headers
         body :  //passing body
         }

this.http.delete("url", options);
```

Not able to figure out how to observe response with status code. 
With using this, below does not work

```
observe : "body"
```